# If-statement doesn't work as expected

Tags: php, variables, if-statement

I would expect the last if-statement to be true, but it echos out: $var is type, max or min.

Can anybody explain what exactly is happening? Because I don't understand.

```
$var = 'required';

if($var == 'unique') {
    echo '$var is unique.';
} else if($var == ('type' || 'max' || 'min')) {
    echo '$var is type, max or min.';
} else if($var == 'required') {
    echo '$var is required.';
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You won't be able to use `||` like this. The proper way would be:

```
if ($var == 'type' || $var == 'max' || $var == 'min')
```

If there are more arguments to check, consider using [in_array](http://php.net/in_array) instead, it'll make the check more concise:

```
if (in_array($var, ['type', 'max', 'min', 'some', 'other', 'string', 'to', 'check']))
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because `('type' || 'max' || 'min')` is an expression that evaluates to boolean `true`, which means you're asking PHP to evaluate `($var == true)`. Since it's not empty or null, the expression is true. Change it to:

```
if ($var == 'type' || $var == 'max' || $var == 'min')
```

Answer (score 2):

What is happening here is that php is first evaluating `('type' || 'max' || 'min')`. This evaluation is true. Afterwards the comparison of `'required'` and `true` is being evaluted to true. This happens because when comparing a boolean to a string, the string is casted as true unless the string is 0. Referring to this table of comparison results may prove helpful https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php.

You want:

```
$var = 'required';

if($var == 'unique') {
    echo '$var is unique.';
} else if($var == 'type' || $var == 'max' || $var == 'min') {
    echo '$var is type, max or min.';
} else if($var == 'required') {
    echo '$var is required.';
}
```

I would even suggest doing === to make sure it does an absolute string comparison in case $var is ever passed in as a boolean or another type.

```
$var = 'required';

if($var === 'unique') {
    echo '$var is unique.';
} else if($var === 'type' || $var === 'max' || $var === 'min') {
    echo '$var is type, max or min.';
} else if($var === 'required') {
    echo '$var is required.';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
($var == ('type' || 'max' || 'min'))
```

You can't write like this. You shoul write it

```
($var == 'type' || $var ==  'max' || $var == 'min'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
$var = 'required';

if($var == 'unique') {
    echo '$var is unique.';
} else if($var == 'type' || $var == 'max' || $var == 'min')) {
    echo '$var is type, max or min.';
} else if($var == 'required') {
    echo '$var is required.';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the correct way is:

```
if($var=='type'||$var=='max'||$var=='min')
```